# what is third party library license?

Tags: android, dependencies, libraries

i'm developing app on android and my app contains many third party library dependencies such as gson, okHttp, Picasso etc.

1) so do i need to mention in my app that i have used this libraries in my app?

2) what it means by Licensed under the Apache License?

3) what if i don't add dependency and direct copy the library files or include library module to my app?

4) what is the meaning of

```
Copyright 2016 .......

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
```

do i need to get license to use this?

Comment: follow the link and read the license. some of them tell you to notice the users about the distribution of third party software, some a just free to use and modify. Read the license!!

Comment: They are open source libraries, use, modify, compile or do anything what you want. )

Comment: You should mention the open source lib you are using in in your app. Even if it's contain any licenses like MIT, Apache etc.

Comment: @SudheeshR is it compulsory? just asking to keep in mind.

Comment: Not all licenses are compulsory, but its a way of conveying our(developers) big thanks to the library creators for making our job easy. Think by yourself, without that libs will your project can be completed so fast ?

Comment: Your are free to use it but under license :)  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
To apply the license in your project, read this http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#apply